# How env var is resolved in distroless container?

Tags: command-line, bash, kubernetes

I am using a distroless container for my app and normally I start my app as follow:

```
java -jar $ARG1 $ARG2 app.jar
```

In distroless image I gave only

```
CMD ["app.jar"]
```

Args are predefined env var in container or local machine. The point here is that AFAIK env vars are resolved by shell/bash but when the container has no sh/bash how env vars will be resolved. I am running my app in K8S and the app is able o use env var from K8S. I wonder how this happened? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean, "resolved by"?

Comment: reading env var @muru

Comment: Environment variables are set by the parent process when creating a child process. They just exist in the child's memory - the child process is free to read them without the need for any shell

Comment: @muru what/who is the parent process in this context then? I mean k8s start the container which is isolated from machine its running on.

Comment: But K8s knows your container definition and the env vars in the image, right? It can set those when starting the container.

Comment: I wasn't aware of how this working behind the scene. I thought env var will be read by shell always. Thanks @muru